# writeSparseArray support SparseArray<int[]>?

Tags: java, android, sparse-array

I have a param in `SparseArray<int[]>` , and want to *serialize* it.

But the `writeSparseArray(Object)` for Parcelable seems not support `int[]`.
Is there any other way to serialize the `SparseArray<int[]>`,Or only change `int[]` to Object?

Comment: You can write your arrays in loop, as first param add SparseArray size.

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak you mean split the SparseArray<int[]> in int[]s and put by writeIntArray(int[]), writeArray(index)? But, how to read out it by readIntArray? Distinguish by new param?

Comment: I check it and I public post

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak Could you give me a sample code? Thanks.

Comment: You can check my solution. I hope it will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked Parcel.writeSparseArray() method and in my opinion there is some issue because this method should be generic like writeList(). It looks like:

```
public final void writeSparseArray(SparseArray<Object> val)
```

and should be

```
public final void writeSparseArray(SparseArray<? extends Object> val)
```

or

```
public final <T> void writeSparseArray(SparseArray<T> val)
```

or

```
public final void writeSparseArray(SparseArray val)
```

So you have to implement your own implementation of this method for SparseArray  object. I am not sure that it is the best solution but you can try this:

```
public void writeSparseArray(Parcel dest, SparseArray<int[]> sparseArray) {
    if (sparseArray == null) {
        dest.writeInt(-1);
        return;
    }
    int size = sparseArray.size();
    dest.writeInt(size);
    int i=0;
    while (i < size) {
        dest.writeInt(sparseArray.keyAt(i));
        dest.writeIntArray(sparseArray.valueAt(i));
        i++;
    }
}

private SparseArray<int[]> readSparseArrayFromParcel(Parcel source){
    int size = source.readInt();
    if (size < 0) {
        return null;
    }
    SparseArray sa = new SparseArray(size);
    while (size > 0) {
        int key = source.readInt();
        int[] value = source.createIntArray();
        sa.put(key, value);
        size--;
    }
    return sa;
}
```

Comment: Welcome I'm glad that I could help you.